# Join Table records are being deleted and created (ORM)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, join

I have a many to many relation in hibernate with extra columns in the join table. When I save the main entity without any impact on the relations between both tables (join table), the record in the join table are deleted and created instead of updated. How wonder how to avoid this?

I know this issue can be solved in @ManyToMany relation by using Set<> collection instead of List<>. Not sure how to achieve this here.

My tables are

```sql
APPLICATIONS
  ID                  NUMBER NOT NULL,
  USER_ID             NUMBER(1),
  STATUS              VARCHAR2(10)

APPLICATION_OPENINGS
  ID                  NUMBER NOT NULL,
  OPENING_ID          NUMBER NOT NULL,
  APPLICATION_ID      NUMBER NOT NULL,
  PRIORITY            NUMBER NOT NULL

OPENINGS
  ID                  NUMBER NOT NULL,
  NAME                VARCHAR2(512) NOT NULL,
  LOCATION_ID         NUMBER
```

My entity relations are defined as

Application.java

```java
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "application")
    private List<ApplicationOpening> openings;
```

ApplicationOpening.java

```java
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "APPLICATION_ID")
    private Application application;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="OPENING_ID")
    private Opening opening;
```

Opening.java

```java
    No reference to the Join Entity ApplicationOpening
```

DAO Service

```java
    applicationDAO.save(application);
```

For the case when save is executed on the Application DAO without modifying anything for example (so no impact on the relation) the records in the Join Table APPLICATION_OPENING are deleted and created again as shown below .

```sql
delete from APPLICATION_OPENINGS where id=?|delete from APPLICATION_OPENINGS where id=388
delete from APPLICATION_OPENINGS where id=?|delete from APPLICATION_OPENINGS where id=387

insert into APPLICATION_OPENINGS (APPLICATION_ID, PRIORITY, OPENING_ID, id) values (55, 1, 28, 412)
insert into APPLICATION_OPENINGS (APPLICATION_ID, PRIORITY, OPENING_ID, id) values (55, 2, 26, 413)
```

How can I avoid this?. I would much appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

As you said changing the list to set will resolve this issue.

For achieving this just change `private List<ApplicationOpening> openings;` to `private Set<ApplicationOpening> openings;` no other changes required.

The reason behind this is, If we are using List as a mapped attribute in hibernate without indexed column, hibernates treats it as a Bag. Since Hibernate handles List as a Bag (Unordered collection with non unique values. The best feature of a bag is that you can get the number of occurrences of an object through the API With a list, there is no way to do the same without iterating through the whole list.) as soon as we delete and add a element in this collection. Hibernate issues a SQL to delete all the elements first from join table which are no supposed to be deleted and then it re-insert all of them back from the Bag.

Refer this [article](http://lkumarjain.blogspot.com/2013/07/why-hibernate-does-delete-all-entries.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks Alien, when you say "mapped attribute in hibernate without indexed", what do you mean. 
In my case the join table Entity has its own Id mapped (see below).

`   @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "OPENING_ID_GEN", sequenceName = "SQ_CFC_VACANCIES", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator = "OPENING_ID_GEN")
    private Long id;`